# How do I decode the stamp on the back of this photograph

Tags: prints, date, forensics

FOTO-KOCH   E725   FRANKFURT-M. on the back of an old photo.
Was photograph taken in Frankfurt or just developed there?

Comment: Foto Koch is a big German photography/electronics retailer based in Düsseldorf if I'm not mistaken. Not sure if they have branches in other cities.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly only developed there. These are markings added during the printing process.

There is usually nothing on a film that tells where the photo was taken (except perhaps on very specialized cameras for aerial survey/recon), and when there is it is on the photo side of the print.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the lab's doing. Of course, the photograph could also have been taken in Frankfurt, but that has nothing to do with the stamp on the back. My best guess would be that FotoKoch is the lab, E725 is the Contax II Zeiss Ikon (perhaps the lens they used for the enlarger?), or it means "developed in Frankfurt, manually".

Is there a date anywhere on the picture? Would love to see it!

Comment: Frankfurt am Main is not close to Berlin. If you mean the Frankfurt that is close to Berlin, that is Frankfurt an der Oder.

Comment: And just to follow up on the previous comment, "the" Frankfurt (5th largest city in Germany) _is_ Frankfurt am Main. (Main and Oder being rivers.)

Comment: BTW, how do you connect E725 with Contax II Zeiss Ikon?

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks for the correction. Frankfurt an der Oder.

Comment: I just did a google search on E725 and the above mentioned Foto-Koch etc., and it brought up a large amount of Contax II cameras, so I figured maybe the Lab used that number as a way to know with what lens it was enlarged with? In case of recurring orders.